# How to show random array's items only once in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui, core-motion

I'm trying to recreate a popular game: Heads up, basically the user has to try to guess the name putting the phone on his head, with friends' suggestions...if he raises the head he skips the word, if he lowers the head it means he guessed the name and he earns a point. He has limited time. I need that every time the user raises/lowers his head, the array's name changes, and each name must appear only once. Any suggestions?

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreMotion

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    let queue = OperationQueue()
    @State private var roll = Double.zero
    
    @State private var people = ["John", "Marcus", "Steve", "Eric", "Philip"].shuffled()
    @State private var randomPerson = Int.random(in: 0...4)
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State private var timeRemaining = 10
    @State private var score = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                //Show a red background and "SKIP" if the user raises head
                if roll < 1 {
                    Color.red
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                    
                    Text("SKIP")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                } else if roll > 2.1 {
                //Show a green background and "CORRECT" if user lowers head
                    Color.green
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                    
                    Text("CORRECT")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .onAppear {
                            score += 1
                        }
                } else {
                //Otherwise show a cyan back with array's name
                    Color.cyan
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                    
                    Text(people[randomPerson])
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                
                Text("\(timeRemaining)")
                    .font(.system(size: 39))
                    .padding(.bottom, 200)
                    .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                        if timeRemaining > 0 {
                            timeRemaining -= 1
                        }
                    }
                
                Text("Score: \(score)")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.top, 200)
            }
            .onAppear {
                //Detect device motion
                self.motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: self.queue) { (data: CMDeviceMotion?, error: Error?) in
                    guard let data = data else {
                        print("Error: \(error!)")
                        return
                    }
                    let attitude: CMAttitude = data.attitude
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.roll = attitude.roll
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just drop shown one from the array, and to reset keep original constant array, that's it.

Comment: @Asperi What do you mean? Can you explain it better?

Comment: Every time a randomPerson is shown, then remove `people[randomPerson]` then decrement the upper limit of the random number range.

Comment: Since you shuffle your array initially, you can use `people.removeFirst()` or `people.removeLast()` to get the randomized  first or last element from the array. These calls remove the element and return it. You don't need to use `randomPerson` as an index. You have already shuffled array. This way you don't have to track your count, just check that `people` is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

1. a state variable for current selected person

> @State private var currerntPerson : String = ""

2. a function to get random person

> getRandomPerson()

3. change TextView show selected person name:

> ```
> Text(currerntPerson)
>    .font(.largeTitle)
>    .bold()
>    .foregroundColor(.white)
>    .onAppear {
>         getRandomPerson()
>    }
> ```

====
All code here:

```
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
let queue = OperationQueue()
@State private var roll = Double.zero

@State private var people = ["John", "Marcus", "Steve", "Eric", "Philip"].shuffled()
@State private var randomPerson = Int.random(in: 0...4)

let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
@State private var timeRemaining = 10
@State private var score = 0
@State private var currerntPerson : String = ""

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            //Show a red background and "SKIP" if the user raises head
            if roll < 1 {
                Color.red
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                Text("SKIP")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            } else if roll > 2.1 {
                //Show a green background and "CORRECT" if user lowers head
                Color.green
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                Text("CORRECT")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .onAppear {
                        score += 1
                    }
            } else {
                //Otherwise show a cyan back with array's name
                Color.cyan
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                Text(currerntPerson)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .onAppear {
                        getRandomPerson()
                    }
            }
            
            Text("\(timeRemaining)")
                .font(.system(size: 39))
                .padding(.bottom, 200)
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    if timeRemaining > 0 {
                        timeRemaining -= 1
                    }
                }
            
            Text("Score: \(score)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.top, 200)
        }
        .onAppear {
            //Detect device motion
            self.motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: self.queue) { (data: CMDeviceMotion?, error: Error?) in
                guard let data = data else {
                    print("Error: \(error!)")
                    return
                }
                let attitude: CMAttitude = data.attitude
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.roll = attitude.roll
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
}

func getRandomPerson() {
    if people.count > 0 {
        let index = Int.random(in: 0..<people.count)
        currerntPerson = people[index]
        people.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

Comment: The temporary View structs shouldn't init objects

Comment: @malhal So what would you suggest?

Comment: Mark motionManager, queue and timer as @.State. Then SwiftUI will manage their lifecycle and only init the objects once no matter how many times the View struct is init. You have many @.State, it might help to put all the related ones into their own Struct. See 4:18 in Data Essentials in SwiftUI WWDC 2020

Comment: @Moon It seems to help somehow, but what if I want to do something when all the elements of the array have been shown?

Comment: @Fabez you can add action in func getRandomPerson() { if people.count > 0 {} else {//action when all the elements have been shown}